# Topology on k((t))

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, analysis

$k((t)):=\lbrace (a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}, a_i \in k,\exists \  N \in \mathbb{Z} \   s.t \ \forall \ i<N, a_i=0\rbrace$ where $k$ is a field of char zero. We define componentwise addition and Cauchy product to get a ring which turns out to be a field.  Without any reference to topology, every element in $k((t))$ can be symbolically written as $\Sigma_{n \geq N} a_i t^i $ where $t=(b_i)$ s.t. $b_1=1$ and $b_i=0 \ \forall \ i \neq 1$.

My question being: Is there a topology which can be given to the above set so that the above  formal series makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can put on $k((t))$ a topology which turns it into a topological field.

The most common topology (for general $k$) here is that coming from the natural valuation, and it is actually metrisable, and very similar to $p$-adic topology, if you have encountered it before.

For a series $a$ we can put $\lVert a\rVert:=2^{-N}$ where $N$ is the least index with nonzero coefficient ($\lVert 0\rVert=0$), and then for any $a,b$ the distance is $\lVert a-b\rVert$. In other words, the basic open sets are those of the form $a+t^nk[[t]]$. This is an ultrametric space, so in particular it is zero-dimensional.

Comment: I'm not absolutely certain, but I think this is the same topology as my answer.

Comment: I think deserves to say explicitly that $k((t))$ is the field of fractions of a DVR, namely $k[[t]]$.

Comment: I'm not so sure that this is the case of the OP, otherwise would have also been clear how to introduce a topology on the field of fractions via the discrete valuation.

Comment: @user26857: that was my point. I don't think this is worth adding to the question enough to edit my answer and bump it, but I suppose your comment might be useful for somebody.

Comment: @MattSamuel: It is similar, but not the same. You can't find a product neighbourhood of $0$ which will simultaneosuly separate it from $t^{-n}$, for all natural $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $k$ is given the discrete topology. The sequences in question are functions from $\mathbb Z$ to $k$. The infinite sums you are considering will converge in the topology of pointwise convergence on the space of such functions (or equivalently the product topology).